# Is it possible to build an addon to firefox that can break a loop of alerts?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, modalpopups

Several times I got into conditions my scripts threw alerts in high rates. While there is an alert modal window open, you can't do any other action in the browser. I am looking to develop an add-on that will enable me to kill or suspend the "thread" the alert modal window belongs to.
In What direction should I look?

Comment: Just by the way, Google Chrome has this enabled by default. After the second alert, you can check a box next to the 'ok' button to disable more alerts from being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help?

[How to stop javascript alert from showing after pressing ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804454/how-to-stop-javascript-alert-from-showing-after-pressing-ok)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using alert(); for debugging purposes maybe look for a logger instead?

If you perhaps use Firebug for Firefox (which you should imo) you can make use of the console.log() or .debug() methods to log directly to the Firebug console.